# increase their risk from/of

Tags: prepositions

Can "from" be replaced by" of" in the following? Is there any difference?

> Over-16s with certain health conditions which increase their risk **from** Covid

Comment: Their risk of what?

Comment: risk of Covid-19

Comment: Risk of dying, risk of being sick, risk of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both “risk from” and “risk of” are perfectly acceptable, but mean different things.

The object of “from” is an external peril such as a disease.

The object of “of” is an event that is perilous.

> The risk from COVID is primarily an inability to absorb enough oxygen to survive.

> The risk of getting COVID is reduced by inoculation.